# issues with msi installer on windows xp

Tags: installation, windows-xp, registry, conditional-statements, launch

I am clueless about a recent issue that I encountered while making an MSI installer for Windows XP 64 bit platform.

In the Launch condition of the installer I am trying to read from registry, but the installer is not fetching the correct value. I tried checking for a different Value name, to confirm that its not just one particular Value name, and found it's behaving in the same manner.

I tried to print the fetched registry value data in the error message and realized that in some cases it gets no value at all and in other cases, it fails to get any number that is a part of the complete value data.

For example if  try reading the data for:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework`
- Value Name : InstallRoot
- Value Data: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\`

The data that installer fetched is: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\`. And in some other instances it gets an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registry searches use the 32-bit registry hive by default and the 64-bit hive only if [msidbLocatorType64bit flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is set.

So the solution is to use 2 searches with the same property:

- one for the 32-bit hive
- one for the 64-bit hive (with msidbLocatorType64bit flag)

Please note that Visual Studio setup projects do not support this. Other setup authoring tools do.

Comment: yep.... it works!!!! :)... cant thank you enough..!!! you really got me out of a tight spot... i would have probably never got to the solution myself in due time. I used Orca to make the suggested changes